# Node JS Sequelize: running the same query again is retrieving the previous result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a Web API using Node JS. For database operation, I am using [the Sequalize package](https://sequelize.org/). In my test when I run the same query that gets a record after updating the record again, it is giving me the old/previous result.

Here is my code:

```
let testUser = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: {
          [Op.eq]: testHelper.testUser.email
        }
      }
    })

    let now = new Date();
    //genrate the token in the database before making the request.
    let verificationToken = await VerificationToken.create({
      userId: testUser.id,
      verificationToken: "testing",
      expiresAt: date.addSeconds(now, 40000)
    })

    let requestBody = {
      email: testUser.email,
      password: "Newpassword123",
      confirm_password: "Newpassword123",
      token: "testing"
    }
    const res = await request(app).put("/api/auth/reset-password").send(requestBody);

    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body.error).toBe(false);

    //refresh the user instance by fetching the new record from the database.
    let user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: {
          [Op.eq]: testHelper.testUser.email
        }
      }
    })

    // here user.password and testUser.password are the same even the record is actually updated
```

As you can see in the comment, the password of user object is still the same as the password of testUser object even though the password is updated in the database. How can I fix it to get the latest record?

Comment: share the api code, so, can check the problem, current test script is 100% correct

Comment: Or, the old password is already `Newpassword123` ?